# Using a variable returned by a function in Python 3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, return

I'm trying to figure out how to use  the number returned in this function:

```
def rMax (iVelocity, iTrajectory):
    rangeMax = ((iVelocity**2) * math.sin(math.radians(2 * iTrajectory))) / GRAV
    return rangeMax
```

and apply it to this function (not sure what to put in the parentheses for `t_hMax ()` or what to put to multiply .5 by in the actual equation):

```
def t_hMax (rangeMax):
    TimeMaxHeight = (.5 * rangeMax)
    return TimeMaxHeight
```

Comment: You mean something like `result = rMax(iVel, iTraj)` `new_result = t_hMax(result)`?

Comment: I think so, but where in the code would that go? Before `return rangeMax`?

Comment: It wouldn't be in one of your functions.  Wherever you call `rMax()`, assign a variable to it, in my example `result`, and then use that variable when you call `t_hMax()`

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. I'm still pretty new with coding and have been trying to figure it out for a while. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand what the point of a function is. The return value is what the function sets a variable equal to when you call it. If you copied and pasted your code into a Python compiler, nothing would happen. As an example, in your second function you could say

```
def t_hMax():
    rangeMax = rMax(iVelocity, iTrajectory
    TimeMaxHeight = (.5 * rangeMax)
    return TimeMaxHeight
```

Notice how the function "calls" the first function and assigns the local rangeMax variable to what you return in the first function. You can't use other functions' variables outside that function, which is the point of returning it

Comment: Ya, I didn't really understand the whole point of a function, but I do understand it a lot more now. Thank you for the explanation, it was really helpful.